# Using java beans in jsp

Tags: jsp, javabeans

I am using netbeans 6.9.1 with jsp and tomcat 6 to work on a web project. I want to use javabeans in my projet. Where i have to place the bean class to get worked in my .jsp page..?

Comment: As always in a Java package inside your WAR or in a utility JAR (project). You question is a bit vague, what exactly is the problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To the point: just in the classpath.

If you're using an IDE, just create the source code file in the source folder like as every other Java class. If you use the IDE to build the WAR, then it will automatically take care that the compiled classes end up in the right classpath location of the WAR, namely the `/WEB-INF/classes` folder.